# SQL server Find/delete hidden trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

So I was playing around with triggers and stored procedures.

For the life of me I cannot find or delete this trigger I setup.

This trigger now runs on any table i create.    The message I get is

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Procedure tr_test, Line 6 Could not find
>   stored procedure 'sp_test'.

I cannot find tr_test for the life of me.   I try and drop the trigger and it says it doesn't exist or I don't have permissions.  I am signed in with SA.

> Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 4 Cannot drop the trigger 'tr_test',
>   because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

I've ran several queries to see if i can figure out where this trigger may be but none have returned any results.

```
 select * from sysobjects where xtype = 'TR'
```

I've even restarted the server thinking it may be held in memory etc.

Any idea how I can find this hidden trigger.

Comment: Try to find Trigger using this query select * from sys.triggers

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing this in reference to your recent question about creating ddl triggers. You have to use a slightly different syntax to drop ddl triggers. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173497.aspx

Comment: Your a god sent.  Last question.  I still have triggers running on table create.  How do i tell what triggers run on that command?

Comment: Right there in the big box of IMPORTANT information in the link I sent....For DDL triggers, use sys.triggers.